# Extract value from deep associative array with multiple stdClass Object

Tags: php, associative-array

I'm trying to access a value from an extremely complicated associative array:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [return] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [entries] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [key] => LAUNCH_DATE
                                    [value] => 2016/07/20
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [key] => COUNTRIES
                                    [value] => AU
                                )
```

I've tried this to get the value 'AU' but with no luck unfortunately:

```
$test = $array_store->return->entries->1->value;
echo $test;
```

This is very difficult and I'm struggling. I managed to extract from a more simple array but this one is too deep. Please help - trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
$test = $array_store->return[0]->entries[1]->value;
echo $test;
```

Comment: @AmyNeville it will work based on your data shown to you.

Comment: I think `return` create problem in fetching data

Comment: @AmyNeville  also when you use `json_decode()` use second parameter `true` so that data will convert to normal array instead of `STD class object array`. Manipulation become more easy